# View controllers that are still open are keeping my app from being able to quit

Tags: swift, cocoa, viewcontroller

I wanted to do a quick cocoa version of my developing iOS app to help me test, as you probably already know - it was not quick but I've learned a lot. I only have one little problem left. Ok, there's probably something all wrong with the way I did this but now it's so close to being all good except this one little thing - I can't figure out how to exit the app at the end.

I'm pretty sure it's because I have a few view controllers still active stacked on via sheet-style segues. Is there a way to just close all view controllers and exit an app? Or if not, how can I do this? I've tried all kinds of things - I know I could put a “quit” button on each of the 3 view controllers that need to close before getting back to the original “intro” type screen which is the only screen you can quit my app from but I don't really want people to have to do that.

Comment: it is not clear what is actually preventing your app from exiting. could you elaborate it more?

Comment: view controllers that aren't dismissed. Like when you try to close an app that has a dialog box open still - it dings at you. I'm hearing that sound and I know i have left behind open view controllers. So I was looking for either a way to dismiss a view controller from a different view controller or, even better - is there a way to dismiss all view controllers? thanks

Comment: Funny that I noticed a Microsoft Office for Mac update with this same type issue. Check for updates came up - it found an update so the window popped down a sheet style window that said what about click here to install update. I clicked there, started to do the update and it wanted to close the "check for updates" screen to complete the update. I clicked "close it automatically" and it tried to close the updater and because of that popover it just dinged at me. I had to click 'cancel' on that popover before I could quit the update checker and then finish the install. Least I'm not the only 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app cannot quit due to some *modal* view being displayed, you can try setting your `NSWindow` [`preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:) property to `NO`:

```
window.preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal = false //--swift
[window setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO] //--objc
```

This should be done on each modal window you open.

EDIT:

An important point to keep in mind is that you should set the above property on the window associated to the alert -- not your main window. If I create programmatically an `NSAlert`, then this will work:

```
let alert = NSAlert()
let w = alert.window as NSWindow //-- alert.window return `id`, so let's cast it
w.preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal = false
```

So, you can either bind your sheet to a variable, then set its  `preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal` property, or you can try the runtime attributes on the sheet itself (specifying the full key path, including window.prevents...).

Comment: I think that should do it - thank you very much. I don't really know enough about it I guess to "clarify how I present my view controllers" more than when I wrote "I have a few view controllers still active stacked on via sheet-style segues".  I held the Ctrl button and drug from one view controller to a new one and picked "sheet" out of the list and named it and using that in my code - I don't have any issues except when I get to the end and want to quit - but I think what you are saying here should do the trick - thanks again.

Comment: Hey, you are right about the fact that saying "stacked on via sheet-style segues" you had said pretty much everything! I removed my comment from my answer. I was maybe reading too quickly... in any case, I do not think you need to have points to accept or upvote answers... btw, could you try my suggestion out?

Comment: Forgot to say that if you choose a different stacking style (sheet is meant for modal things, hence the problem when you try to quit), you will also work around the issue. for that to work, you would need a navigation controller, if you are not using one already...

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I forgot to mention - when I try to click the up arrow on your answer (I'm guessing that's how you vote) it gives me a message that reads "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".

I will definitely try your suggestion out and let you know. I'm actually changed gears and focusing on the iOS version right now to try to get it ready to go for my goal (10 more days) - but I should be able to just try this real quick on the Mac version tomorrow and post back here. Thanks again

Comment: I see the issue with upvoting. In any case, you should also see a checkmark somewhere: that would mean that you acknowledge the answer has solved your problem.

Comment: Sergio, thanks so much for your patience with me. Uhmm, I'm trying to do this and can't figure out how. At some point in the future maybe I'll be like the cool kids and not use the storyboard for everything, but it's getting the job done for me at least when it comes to the iOS version of this app, which what I really care about.

So anyway, I'm not sure how to use this [window setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO]

I'm using Swift too btw, but I tried 2 different things - 1) I set up an IBOutlet and connected to my window (I only have one window, btw - I don't totally understand) & .

Comment: ... and I just named it 'window' and then put this:
window.preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal = false
in my viewDidLoad()
So this gave me an uncaught exception:
2015-02-05 10:49:40.065 US State Capitals - StudyCraft[25208:13204531] [<NSWindow 0x6000001e4a00> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.

So then I tried - 2) This was a real shot in the dark because I have no idea what this "User Defined Runtime Attributes" is ...

Comment: ...really for (in the storyboard) but I added a value here for my window with the key path "preventsAppplicationTerminationWhenModal" and set it to false. No crash with this attempt but didn't fix it either.

Honestly, I'm sure what you are saying should fix the issue and I'll just mark this as answered because you did answer it. I'm trying to get the iOS version out now and may come back to the Cocoa version after that and will redo this completely and do it the way you suggest with the nav controller. Thanks again so much

Comment: I had not noticed the swift tag... in any case, the error about `valueForUndefinedKey` means that you are calling `window.prevents...` on the wrong object, one that has no `prevents...` property defined. Both approach will work, but you should set the property on your sheet window, not your main window. see my edit...